# How to migrate from docker-compose v2 to docker-compose v3 with swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

My current `docker-compose.yml` is

```
version: "2"

services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./misc/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - /static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web

  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  web:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: bash -c "python /code/manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python /code/manage.py migrate && /code/run_gunicorn.sh"
    volumes:
      - /static:/data/web/static
      - /media:/data/web/media
      - .:/code
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db


volumes:
  pgdata:
    external:
      name: orderstore
```

How to update it to the latest docker-compose revision (3.4) with swarm mode support? At least now it's saying that `build` key is not supported.

My very goal is to deploy it to `AWS EC2/ECS`. If it's possible - please describe me how to properly deploy it to AWS.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of an automatic way of migrating compose file. The changes are documented in [Compose file versions and upgrading](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-2x-to-3x). You need to do the migration manually.